# javascript code fills html paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

best regards, I want to write a javascript code that write to Paragraph `<P><br data-mce-bogus="1"></P>` which exists inside this

```
<html><head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="contentMessage_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; height: 260px;">
<tbody>
<td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
<iframe id="contentMessage_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for help" style="width: 100%; height: 216px; display: block;">
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta content="IE=7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>
<br data-mce-bogus="1">
</p>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</td>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this code

```
javascript:document.getElementById('contentMessage_ifr').contentDocument.body.innerHTML="it works";
```

is there something wrong with my code , it works fine on [w3schools javascript editor](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_text)

thanks in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Wj3CE/ Seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting the ID of the iframe.
Try getting a hold of the paragraph.
Here's a jsfiddle example which should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/kakashi/QR9N8/

The relevant code you want, if you want to use jQuery, is:

```
$('p:has(br[data-mce-bogus=1])').append("<p>Hi There</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your html code isn't very clean, you are missing some html tags like "html" and "tr", try this html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="contentMessage_tbl" class="mceLayout" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" role="presentation" style="width: 100%; height: 260px;">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="mceIframeContainer mceFirst mceLast">
<iframe id="contentMessage_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:"""   allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text AreaPress ALT-F10 for toolbar. Press ALT-0 for  help" style="width: 100%; height: 216px; display: block;">
<html>
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta content="IE=7" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" dir="ltr" style="font-size: 12px; font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;">
<p>
<br data-mce-bogus="1">
</p>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>​
```